# Error when I try to add a new record to Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I want to save data to the CoreData, but I get the next error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
reason: '[<NSEntityDescription 0x7fc428f75940> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'
```

This is my code:

```
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UnreadMessages")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result: NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        let newRecord: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UnreadMessages", inManagedObjectContext: context)!

        if result.count > 0 {
            print("It exists")
            print(context)
        } else {
            print("it's a new record")
            newRecord.setValue(user.jidStr, forKey: "username")
            newRecord.setValue("1", forKey: "count")

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
            print(context)
        }
    } catch _ {

    }
```

it reaches until:

```
print("it's a new record")
newRecord.setValue(user.jidStr, forKey: "username")
```

prints `It's a new record` and crashes! What is wrong with my code?

It's my CoreData screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you do not find a matching record you need to first insert into the managed object context something like this...

```
   do {
    let result: NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    if result.count > 0 {
        // NEW CODE: Print the username if found in result[0]                         
        let userFound = result[0]                                                 
        let usernamefound = String(userFound.valueForKey("username")!)            
        print("It exists  \(usernameFound)")                                      

        print(context)
    } else {
        print("it's a new record")

        let newRecordEntity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UnreadMessages", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        let newRecord = UnreadMessages(entity: newRecordEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newRecord.setValue(user.jidStr, forKey: "username")
        newRecord.setValue("1", forKey: "count")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Can I search here like `select count where username = some_name_here`?

Comment: Hi, if you only want to get records for a given username you need to use a NSPREDICATE.  If you have multiple conditions then you need a compound predicate.  I updated my answer above with an example using a predicate for username = some_username

Comment: thanks! But it returns me `Use of unresolved identifier 'UnreadMessages'` this error

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  I do not have a mac in front of me today so I can not debug this.  If it is the "let newRecord = UnreadMessages..." line, try the example from Jody's answer above.

Comment: yes, I did it already. The last question, I fetched request and got `<NSManagedObject: 0x7fd7406992e0> (entity: UnreadMessages; id: 0xd000000000040014 <x-coredata://7EA53B7F-37BF-4FF3-B02E-629BEC62260E/UnreadMessages/p1> ; data: {
    count = 1;
    username = "Bob";
})`. How can I print just username from here?

Comment: Added print statement for the username above

Comment: No, it crashes. I tried this. Look at my code: `let fetchResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) for obj in fetchResults { print(obj[0]) }`. it crashes, unexpectedly nil

Answer (score 4):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:  this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key username.'

This is your big clue.  It means that you are asking an instance of `NSEntityDescription` to use KVC to set an attribute with the name "username" but that class does not support that key.

> prints It's a new record and crashes! What is wrong with my code?

Well, your code does not create a new "record."  This code

```
let newRecord: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UnreadMessages", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
```

creates a `NSEntityDescription`, which can be used to create an `NSManagedObject`.

To create a new "record" you want to call

```
let newRecord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
                    "UnreadMessages",
                    inManagedObjectContext:context)
```

Thus, you can now see that you are trying to set "username" on an entity-description, and not a managed-object.

Comment: it seems work, but what if it exists there? Can I search here like `select count where username = some_name_here`?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade - While there may be an SQL database underneath, core data is not a database, so you don't issue SQL statements.  You simply ask the persistent store if it has an instance of your object.  In core data, this is called a fetch, and you can find out all about it by reading the documentation on `NSFetchRequest`.  Basically, you fetch by some key, and if the object is there, you update it and if not you create a new one.